# Why Is One Question Closed for Legal Advice and the Other Upvoted?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

So I recently submitted a question that got shot-down immediately for asking legal advice. It is as follows: [Hybrid Source License That Is Basically Open Source but Prevents Competition?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425139/hybrid-source-license-that-is-basically-open-source-but-prevents-competition)

However, overall the question is pretty similar to this one, except in this one they make the mistake of asking for an Open Source license to do the same thing, which cannot exist: [Open Source License that prevents re-selling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179383/open-source-license-that-prevents-re-selling)

Could someone explain to me what the main difference is between these two questions that caused mine to be closed as opposed to the upvotes the other received?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I think it's time we just make all licensing questions off-topic](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/i-think-its-time-we-just-make-all-licensing-questions-off-topic)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for pointing out the older question. I'd stress older - it was posted in 2012. What we consider acceptable has evolved quite a bit since then. However, both questions straddle the line between "legal advice" and "seeking recommendations", both of which are off-topic here. The older question has been closed and locked (due to its age, votes, and views).