# What can be done about "funny" comments?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a number of questions where there are a few useful clarifying questions in the comments, and then a funny comment, and the funny comment has several upvotes. once the comments fold, this is going to bump a useful comment away. Is there anything sensible to do about this?

Comment: Laugh at the comment???

Comment: two guys walk into a bar...

Comment: Do cannibals not eat clowns because they taste funny?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We [clean up comments that have outlived their use](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/how-do-our-moderators-and-community-members-feel-about-cleaning-up-comment-nois/1508#1508), and joke comments outlive their use as soon as they're posted.

Flag them as *chatty* or *not constructive* and they'll be deleted.

Comment: Funny comments shouldn't be deleted until they haver several upvotes. They are not outlived if not many people have laughed after reading them.